# CMake: Generating batch file calling cl.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, cmake

CMake is a **build system generator** supporting different build systems and environments like make, visual studio, code-blocks, eclipse-cdt, etc...
To generate a project, you can use the -G option to specify the project generator.

Is there an option, are there any projects, or is it possible to write a **generator** that creates batch files calling **cl.exe** so I don't have to open visual studio every time?

Comment: If you call `cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Debug` from the command line in the build directory you don't have to open Visual Studio. Instead the solution is built from MSBuild.

Comment: @vre thx for the example!

Comment: You may want to consider a `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${CMAKE_VS_DEVENV_COMMAND}" CACHE INTERNAL "")` call before your `project()` command for newer versions of CMake (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173970/msbuild-exe-has-stopped-cmake-error/41181777#41181777)). This uses `DevEnv` instead of `MSBuild` for the `--build` command for the Visual Studio generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake is able to invoke the build tool (MSBuild in this case) by itself, using the `--build` option. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183248/the-option-build-of-cmake) for more details.